# LibGdx default Application cases the following Error Message ? how to Resolve

Tags: android, libgdx

-- Android Studio 2.1.3 with Latest SDK Running on WIndows 10.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java" 
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:322)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:216)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

-- Output in Android Emulator Working fine (shows the BadLogic Logo)

-- Desktop Application shows the above Error Message.

Comment: Current libGdx version is 1.9.4

Comment: You've shown no code - just an error dump. As posted, it's unclear what you're asking. You should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: till I did not write any code, this is the Default LibGdx Code (desktop, Android wtih Box2d Code), when i I try to Run as Desktop Application following error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your desktop workiong directory path to your androis assets folder: [Instructions under "Running Your Project"](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA)